# Inquiries : Sometime getting, sometimes not?

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have added a quick contact form in every page so clients can easily get in touch. However, three different things are happening as below:

- sometimes getting inquiries from client. (Genuine I can say, we worked together)
- sometimes getting blank message. with Unknown sender every alternate day.
- Getting nothing. (Whenever I am trying to check whether all pages working or not. I am not getting email on first time. (Sometimes second, third, fourth time works).

My code is as follows:

PHP script I am using:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'    some message '
    );
//echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);exit;
    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
    $email_from = @trim($_POST['email']); 
    $websitelink = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['websitelink'])); 
    $subject = 'iMarketingJunkies: Inquiry'; 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

     // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <'.$email_from.'>' . "\r\n";

    //$email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'myemail@email.com';//replace with your email

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . '<br><br>' . 'Email: ' . $email_from .  '<br><br>' . 'URL: ' . $websitelink . '<br><br>' . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, $headers);

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
    ?>
```

Can anybody please help me to get rid of this. I have tested all pages and I am sure we can't add submit button without any data. I am using Cloudfare.

Thank you

Comment: blank, probably a bot, you dont check anything is filled in before sending

Comment: I am using a particular name while testing. however in that case, sometimes i getting email sometimes not getting.